# Running a command although the connection is close adomd

Tags: c#, adomd.net

I have read the Mirosoft [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/adomd/multidimensional-models-adomd-net-client/connections-in-adomd-net-working-with-connections-and-sessions?view=asallproducts-allversions).When we open a connection and then close it, it is possible to use the session.

I have written this block of code to run a command but I get an error message, which says there is no connection. Do you have any Idee how can I close the connection, but use the session to run a cammand:

```
 try
            {
                using (AdomdConnection adomdConnection = new AdomdConnection("MY Connection String"))
                {
                    adomdConnection.Open();
                    adomdConnection.Close(false);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        String query = @"EVALUATE { BLANK()}";
                        AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new AdomdCommand(query);
                        Console.WriteLine(adomdConnection.SessionID.ToString() + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        AdomdDataReader reader = adomdCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        reader.Close();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(AdomdConnectionException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the examples shown in the document you list, it has:

```
/*First, try to connect to the specified data source.  
If the connection string is not valid, or if the specified  
provider does not support sessions, an exception is thrown. */  
objConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;  
objConnection.Open();  
  
// Now that the connection is open, retrieve the new  
// active session ID.  
strSessionID = objConnection.SessionID;  
// Close the connection, but leave the session open.  
objConnection.Close(false);  
return strSessionID;
```

And in your code specifically, you have:

```
adomdConnection.Open();
adomdConnection.Close(false);
while (true)
{
    String query = @"EVALUATE { BLANK()}";
    AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new AdomdCommand(query);
    Console.WriteLine(adomdConnection.SessionID.ToString() + "  " + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString());
    AdomdDataReader reader = adomdCommand.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Close();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

Wouldn't you want to have this instead (based on the example given)?

```
adomdConnection.Open();
while (true)
{
    String query = @"EVALUATE { BLANK()}";
    AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new AdomdCommand(query);
    Console.WriteLine(adomdConnection.SessionID.ToString() + "  " + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString());
    AdomdDataReader reader = adomdCommand.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Close();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
adomdConnection.Close(false);
```

It seems as though it's complaining because you're closing the connection before you even use it, according to the order in which your code looks to be operating. Try moving the `adomdConnection.Close(false);` after your `while` loop.